# Test data for geocoder

Tags: data, geocoding

Can you suggest good international test dataset for geocoder testing? Best if it would have unstructured and structured addresses, and coordinates, but even significant number (thousands, millions) of unstructured addresses would be good start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps http://openplaques.org.  You can obtain *address*, *coordinates* and details on the cleanliness of the original geocoding for many of the plaques.

Not a very even geographical or language distribution, and also slightly odd addresses in general, but it's an interesting dataset to use.

Answer (score 1):

Try Open Addresses database. It has over 500 million records. It is available for download [here](https://results.openaddresses.io/).

[image]

The good part is that it has data from all world regions.
I suggest you start with Latin America as it is one of the hardest nuts to crack when comes to address testing. Then do Europe, then Asia. Leave the USA for last as addresses are most standardized there and by that time your test cases should cover it well.

Comment: What does your answer have to do with your company?  It looks like you are including a signature with a link to your website in the guise of, in this instance, an unnecessary disclaimer, and so I am editing it out.  In any event please do not include a link in any disclaimer.